# My Program is throwing an error that claims the vector subscript is out of range. (C++)

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am trying to create a vector that holds a user summited value worth of my class object. Unfortunately, I am running into an error that states my vector's subscript is out of range. My main guess is there might be something wrong with the way I am analyzing each element of the vector or possibly the way I am creating the vector. Any suggestions would be gladly appreciated!

```
...
    unsigned int population = 3;
    vector<Platypus> pop;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < population; i++) {
        pop.push_back(Platypus());
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < population; j++) {
            if (i%(int)fabs(4 - eatAmount) == 0) {
                pop.at(j).eat();
            }
            if(pop.at(j).getAge() >= 24 && 
                pop.at(j).getGender()=='F' && 
                pop.at(j).getAlive()==1 && 
                pop.at(j).getMutant()!=0){
                pop.push_back(pop.at(j).hatch());
            }
            if (i > 30) {
                pop.at(j).age_me(1);
            }
            if (j % 3 == 0 && j!=0) {
                pop.at(j).fight(pop.at(j - 1));
            }
                pop.at(j).print(cout);
        }
    }
    for (int i = pop.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        if (pop[i].getAlive() == 0) {
            pop.erase(pop.begin()+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = pop.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        if (pop[i].getAlive() == 0) {` Have another look at this one.

Comment: I'm also concerned about this line: `pop.push_back(pop.at(j).hatch());`. Can't be sure without seeing the definition of `Platypus`, but if `hatch()` is returning a reference inside the object, then the `vector` could be resized to make space for the new element, thereby invalidating the reference!

Comment: If you run you code in a debugger it'll show you which line is causing the error. If you want us to help you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You could write instead of `for (int i = pop.size(); i > 0; i--)` this: `for (int i = pop.size(); i--;)`. Looks a bit strange but decrements `i` just after condition but before accessing the vector. Even empty vector is handled correctly. (The decrement of `i` becomes negative (or wraps over for unsigned counter) when `i` is 0 but luckily `i` isn't used after this anymore.) It's one of the rare cases where post-decrement really makes sense. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is you culprit:

```cpp
for (int i = pop.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        if (pop[i].getAlive() == 0) { // HERE
            pop.erase(pop.begin()+i);
        }
    }
```

On the first loop iteration, `i` is initialised to the size of the vector. To turn this into a valid index, you need to subtract 1, or otherwise you go out of bounds.